# How to keep same values in select box when database have 2 names for same field?

Tags: php

Please check the database screenshot and code below

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxv5.png)

```
<select class="half" id="driver" name="driverage">
<option value="21-24" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == '21-24'){?>selected<?php }?>>21-24</option>
<option value="25+" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driver_age'] == '25+'){?>selected<?php }?>>25+</option>
```

I only want to keep the same values in select box after serach

Comment: `if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == 25+)` -- what do you expect this to do? That's invalid syntax in any language.

Comment: yes will you please help me how to write this syntax?

Comment: Example when i select value 5 from passenger field and click on search button even then value remain 5 i also want to do the same for driver age so i copy the syntax of passengers field @ rickdenhaan

Comment: Oh, right, I get it. You're trying to compare against a ***string*** and not a ***number***. In that case, you should use `if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == '25+')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="half" id="driver" name="driverage">
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == "21-24"){?>selected<?php }?>>21-24</option>
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == "25+"){?>selected<?php }?>>25+</option>        
</select>
```

Comment: not working as it gives error "no result found"..It picks valus from database and i only have 21-24 and 25+ value in database and when i select 25+ it and search the form it again goes back to 21-24

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gfruqu please check this screenshot it is after serach passengers filed is working fine as i select 4 passenges before search and driver age filed set back to 21-24

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings as if they're numbers. You need to wrap the values in quotation marks:

```
<select class="half" id="driver" name="driverage">
    <option value="21-24" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == '21-24'){?>selected<?php }?>>21-24</option>
    <option value="25+" <?php if(@$_REQUEST['driverage'] == '25+'){?>selected<?php }?>>25+</option>        
</select>
```

Note that I have also re-added the `value=""` attributes as they were in your screenshot of the original code.

On a side-note: please drop all the `@`-symbols. All they do is hide warnings, which means you're not aware when things aren't working properly.

Comment: prntscr.com/gfruqu please check this screenshot it is after serach passengers filed is working fine as i select 4 passenges before search and driver age filed set back to 21-24 @rickdenhaan

Comment: Can you `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` to see what the actual value is after submitting the form?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gfrzf7  this is the original code ..I only want that when i click on the search button value in the fields remains same ..Passengers fields working fine so i copy the code and try to use it with driver age but it didn't work @rickdenhaan

Comment: That code is missing your `if`-statements. But the code you posted in your question is missing the `value="21-24"` and `value="25+"` attributes. So again: what is the actual value in `$_REQUEST` after submitting the form?

Comment: as i am not good with php but i attached another screenshot of database http://prntscr.com/gfs21o hope this helps. 1 more thin when i remove "+" then it works fine but plus sign also removes from the fields  ...@#rickdenhaan

Comment: @user3784723 That won't help. Please add the following code: `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` and let me know what it gives as value for the `driverage` when you submit the form.

Comment: <select class="half" id="driver" name="driverage">
    <option <?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>>21-24</option>
    <option <?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>>25+</option>        
</select> i need to put it like this..

Comment: @user3784723 I've updated my answer, can you check if it works properly if you add the `value=""` back into the `<option>`s?

Comment: @user3784723 No, outside a HTML tag, for example: `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?><select class="half"...`

Comment: updated answer is not working and <?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?> it shows "array ()" in front end

Comment: Even after submitting the form?

Comment: no sorry after submitting the form it shows Array ( [car_type] => 0 [pickup] => 0 [return] => 0 [residence] => US/Canada [driver_age] => 25+ [passengers] => No. of Passengers [search] => )

Comment: `driver_age`? Are you sure you have `<select name="driverage">` without the `_`?

Comment: Is there any other way that value remains same in the fields even after click on search

Comment: If the value is actually posted to the server as `driver_age` instead of `driverage`, you need to check for `$_REQUEST['driver_age']` in your if-statement. Is there any javascript processing going on when the form is submitted?

Comment: Database is not directly related to what the form is sending to the server.

Comment: Unless you're overwriting `$_REQUEST` in PHP with what you have in the database, but that would be silly.

Comment: That would explain what you're seeing though, because in your database all entries have a `driverage` (without underscore) of `21-24` so that would make the form `<select>` stay at that value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @rickdenhaan

Comment: @ rickdenhaan sir is there ayy other way to get this done

Comment: @user3784723 I thought you said it worked if you use the underscore?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this actually my client are waiting for me ?

Comment: Actually problem is with database and two fields that is driverage and driver_age..Driver age is for 21-24 and driver_age is for 25+..ANd some vechiles are available for both so i don't know how to do this

Comment: This question was originally about your form. If the problem is with your database, maybe you should start a new question with what you've learned so far and include the code for the form, where you're processing the form and where you're getting the results from the database. Also, check if you're *setting* `$_REQUEST` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Can i add 2 value like 21-24 , 25+ for driverage in database ?

Comment: Generally speaking: yes, you can add anything to your database. But it depends on your database structure and what the effects will be for the rest of your application.

Comment: Since it is a `VARCHAR` column: yes, you can add those values.

Comment: Then that was not the cause of your problem. I recommend starting a new question to bring this under the attention of other developers.

Comment: I deleted driverage and tried to put 21-24 , 25+ in same field driver_age ..but it did not search

Comment: Then the problem is not with your database, but with your PHP code. Again, start a new question.